# MongoDB and Setting --DBPath (Windows)

Tags: c#, windows, mongodb, gridfs

I've successfully managed to create a file cache with mongo, when running with the database in the default database folder everything works a treat.

But if I run it with a custom dbpath I can no longer insert with GridFS. I'm using the official c# driver.

Simply restarting the mongo instance with the defaults solves the issue.

mongod (works).
mongod --dbpath F:\mongo\db (Doensn't work).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was down to file permissions, changed those and it's all sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason that mongod might not be able to find dbpath is if it has an extra \ on the end of the path eg

F:\mongo\db\

I just wanted to add this reason in case someone has my problem and finds this answer like I did when searching.